# How to properly use node-mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I just started using node-mysql2 and I am confused how to use it properly. Examples:

(Implicitly established connection)

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express();

var mysql = require("mysql2");

var conn = mysql.createConnection({ ... });

app.VERB("/", function(req, res){
    conn.query('SELECT 1+1 as test1', function(err, rows) {
        // Show data to user...
        // No .end() needed?
    });
});

app.listen(8000);
```

second example:

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express();

var mysql = require("mysql2");

var conn = mysql.createConnection({ ... });
    conn.connect(function(err){ ... });  // Is it right place to put it here? Or it has to go inside the callback below?

app.VERB("/", function(req, res){
    conn.query("SELECT 1+1 as test1", function(err, rows){
        // Show data to user...
        conn.end(); // .end() necessary?
    });
});

app.listen(8000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I haven’t used [node-mysql2](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2), it is compatible with the original [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) module, so the same usage patterns apply.

The best way to use it is with [connection pooling](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#pooling-connections). That way, the MySQL client will create and destroy connections as needed. Your job is to call `connection.release()` when you no longer need a connection:

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express();

var mysql = require("mysql2");

var pool = mysql.createPool({ ... });

app.VERB("/", function(req, res){
    pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
      if (err) { /* handle the error and bail out */ }
      conn.query('SELECT 1+1 as test1', function(err, rows) {
          conn.release(); /* the connection is released back to the pool */
          if (err) { /* handle the error */ }
          else { /* show data to user */ }
      });
    });
});

app.listen(8000);
```

If your app runs “forever” (a web site for example) then you don’t need to call `pool.end()`. If you’re not using a connection pool, you don’t need to call `connection.end()` after each request. You wouldn’t want to: that would give you the overhead of establishing/tearing down the MySQL connection on every request!

If your app does not run “forever” (a command-line utility, for example), then call `pool.end()` or `connection.end()` just before you exit back to the command-line.

Comment: Thank you... I have one more question. Yes I am building a web site and I understand what you are saying... In this case I should call pool.end() / connection.end() in situation when I am going to for example kill a process, right?

Comment: If you are controlling when your processes are killed, that is a good idea. Clean shutdown. Normally my Express sites just run until they are killed by `upstart` or by Ctrl-C if I’m testing. I don’t bother calling `pool.end()` in that case.